# Calling a Wordpress function out of class

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a woocommerce plugin that has a class `Foo`:

```
function wc_foo_init(){
class WC_Foo extends WC_Shipping_Method{
    $var=get_option(); //gets an option for this session
    function sayHello(){
        echo $var;
    }
new WC_Foo();
}
```

I want to call `sayHello()` out of the `Foo` class:

```
function bar(){
    WC_Foo->sayHello();
}
```

But I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function `sayHello` on a non-object.
```

Comment: Can't you `$something = new WS_Foo(); $something->sayHello();`?

Comment: No. I edited the post. I have another constructor.

Comment: Because `sayHello()` is a normal, non-static method, you'll need an instance of the `WC_Foo` class to call it on. How you create that and its lifecycle in general is something we can't really guess without more information.

Comment: @s_puria, please take a look at my answer and let me know if that's what you are looking for...

Answer (score 0):

Use $this selector if you are calling the method within the class

```
function bar(){
    $this->sayHello();
}
```

If you want to call the method from other place,
you need to instantiate the class like this:

```
$object = new WC_Foo();
$object->sayHello();
```

Or make the method static like this:

```
public static function sayHello(){
    echo "Hello";
}
```

And call it like this:

```
WC_Foo::sayHello();
// this way you dont need $object = new WC_Foo();
```

Comment: Now it gives: `Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in`

Comment: I'm not the downvoter in case you get any, but in the question it's stated: _sayHello() **out of** the Foo class:_. Since it's out of the class, using `$this` doesn't make much of a sense.

Comment: Yes, i just noticed it, so i expanded my answer

Answer (score 0):

You must instantiate class before make call of its methods:

```
$foo = new WC_Foo();
$foo->sayHello();
```

or if your php version is greater than 5.4 you can do:

```
(new WC_Foo())->sayHello();
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the full code, so it's pretty weird what you have there, but let's go.

Since you have a function to init your object, you would probably want to at least return that instance. This code might help you understand:

```
function init_foo(){
    class foo{
        function say(){
            echo 'hello';
        }
    }
    $foo1 = new Foo();
    return $foo1;
}

function bar($foo3){
    $foo3->say();
}

$foo2 = init_foo();
bar($foo2);
```

So, first we create the object and return it. Then we inject it in the bar function, just needing to call the method after that. (I used different var names so it's easier to understand scope)